# Could not get any response in postman for API post request

Tags: postman

I am trying to do a post request in postman for jira Api testing. but keep getting could not get any response error. Please see pictures below. I have turn off SSL certificate as suggest one post here but still not able to get the response. 
[image: POST request in Postman]

[image: error message]

Comment: Where did you deploy your api? IIS?

Comment: In postman with jira api. I also tried to hit directly this URL from the browser also? but getting same error "could not get any response.

Comment: Could you tell me how you came up with your url? because if it's not getting any response then it might be because of your url.

Comment: You might be calling the wrong port

Comment: I opened Chrome address bar and type "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/1/ session and after hit the enter I got "could not get any response" error.  I checked with my internet service provider and confirmed that port-8080 is open on my home server. I tried to disable my firewall but still not working. some one told me my server is not running but I am not sure what server they are talking.

Comment: in postman view>consile I am getting following log:

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/1/session
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers.